# Insert into values as parameter - Python

Tags: python, parameters, insert

I have pretty trivial problem which looks like this:

```
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:/Users/vlcek/Desktop/company.accdb;'
    )
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = connection.cursor()

first_name='Peter'
second_name='Jackson'

sql="Insert into people values (25, ?, ?)"

cursor.execute(sql2(first_name, second_name,))
connection.commit()
```

But I get error message `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

Could someone please tell what could be the problem? If I don't use parameters and just write `'Peter'`, `'Jackson'`, everything works fine.

Comment: First, what is `sql2`? You never define anything with that name.

Comment: Second, the arguments to `execute` are a SQL string, and a tuple of values, like `execute(sql, (first_name, second_name))`.

Comment: Here is your problem `sql2(first_name, second_name,)`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Yes, you are right, I should have used sql2 as a string, it was fine in my code, but I really forget that comma in cursor.execute function, if I type: cursor.execute(sql2, (first_name, second_name,)) it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have anything named `sql2` in the code you posted. But I'm going to assume it's either supposed to be `sql`, or a different SQL query string.

The problem is that you're trying to call that string as if it were a function:

```
sql2(first_name, second_name,)
```

What does it mean to call a string with two arguments? It doesn't make any sense, so Python gives you a `TypeError`.

What I think you're *trying* to do is this:

```
cursor.execute(sql2, (first_name, second_name,))
```

In other words, you don't want to call `sql2` on two arguments and then pass the result to `execute`, you just want to pass `sql2` and a tuple of two values to `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the string sql (typo sql2?) as a function. Instead try:

```
sql="Insert into people values (25, %s, %s)"

cursor.execute(sql,(first_name, second_name))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for tip. I assume that %s is working same like ?, right?

Comment: Yes, here's the django documentation for it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly